# Asp.net Identity 2 Account single entry

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

How to make asp.net identity account single entry?
A user who connects the system and when another person makes entry into that account with same email. I want to auto sign out the previous user.

With your claims? or With your DefaultCookie?

waiting for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the validation interval to 0 so every time the database will be checked for cookie validation:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
```

And, when a user signs in, change his SecurityStamp. This will cause every existing cookie to be invalidated:

```
UserManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(userId);
```